# $L^p$ convergence and interchange of limit and integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question goes as follows:

"Let $f_{n}$ be sequences in $L^{2}$ function, with domain $(a,b)$ and Lebesgue measure.
Now, there is $f$ in $L^{2}(a,b)$ such that $\lim ||f_{n} - f||_{2}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.
If $a$ and $b$ are each finite and $a \leq t \leq  b$, then show: $$\int_{a}^{t}f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{t}f_{n}(x)dx$$

My Thoughts:
My first thought was that the switching of integral and limit would involve use of DCT. However, the  $L^2$ convergence does not satisfy the condition for DCT (which requires convergence in a.e.). Therefore, I thought about "$L^{2}$ implies $L^{1}$ convergence" and reverse triangle inequality to get:
$$||f_{n}||_{1} - ||f||_{1} \leq ||f_{n}-f||_{1}$$
and that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{t}|f_{n}|d\mu = \int_{a}^{t}|f(x)| d\mu$$

However, I think the way I approached is not what the question intended.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Think of an inequality given by names of very famous mathematicians (the fact that $a,b$ are finite is important here).

Comment: @OliverDiaz Wow, a very simple and easy way to show this! thank you so much.

Comment: @peek-a-boo apparently you were referring to Cauchy-Schwarz. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\Big|\int^t_a(f_n(x)-f(x))\,dx\Big|\leq\int^t_a|f_n(x)-f(x)\,dx|=\int^b_a\mathbb{1}_{[a,t]}(x)|f_n(x)-f(x)|\,dx$$
Apply Cauchy-Schartz or Holder's inequality to get
$$
\Big|\int^t_a(f_n(x)-f(x))\,dx\Big|\leq \|\mathbb{1}_{[a,t]}\|_2\|f_n-f\|_2=\sqrt{(t-a)}\|f_n-f\|_2\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$